# New domain on Ubuntu LAMP stack connected to another website

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp, virtualhost

I purchased [bardhakryeziu.com](http://bardhakryeziu.com) and tried to create new virtual host on apache2. What I did was I copied the conf file of my own website [amirrami.com](http://amirrami.com) and just changed the values. Now I have no idea what happened in apache I just know that both domains point to the same website. Even me deleting the virtual host completely and disabling the site, same thing happens. I really don't know what info should I provide for you to be able to help me out. Check the link and see for yourself. Any additional info I'd be happy to provide.

Comment: Are you *sure* everything is configured correctly? Check this out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: @Cody Yes I'm following this tutorial everytime I do this, I almost know it by heart. The only thing I missed was step 6 and I just added the lines but nothing changed. At the moment I have the bardhakryeziu.com disabled and the .conf deleted but it still points to my own website.

Comment: I mean, if you have nothing to lose, completely reinstall the LAMP stack and set it up the right way following that guide (and the prerequisite guides) and see if it works.

Comment: @Cody I'm hosting a company website on my LAMP I don't know if I should do that.

Comment: @Cody the problem was I haven't obtained an SSL certificate for this domain yet and since the other had one it was automatically redirecting. Weird.